# Failing to login in SQL PLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to connect to my Oracle database using SQL PLUS.
I've created a user and could work under its name through Sql Developer or Data Grip - connection there was successful.

In SQL PLUS I get this (wrong username/password):
[image]

I'm pretty sure I didn't make any mistakes in password because it's just 123456.

Here is my listener.ora:
[image]

Here is my tnsnames.ora:
[image]

Here is User info and details in Sql Developer (successful connection):
[image]

Comment: What is the command-line you are using to connect via `SQL*Plus`?  Are you specifying a TNS alias?

Comment: Just start it as `sqlplus Student/123456@//maxim/orclpdb`

Answer (score 0):

You're host it's "Maxim" based on the configs. But your db it's running on "localhost" based on your succesful connection by SQLDev.
Just use :

```
sqlplus 'Student/123456@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=locahost)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orclpdb)))'
```

Take a look to :

http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-connect-with-oracle-database-using-sqlplus-utility/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GS4udgR44Ls

Hope it helps, best!.